# check extension in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to upload only jpg, jpeg and png type images. That's why I want to check extension of uploading images. **All files which extension is updated like .exe file is updated as .jpg or .png file then it allow to upload but I want to prevent it** and upload only original images.
How can I do it in Cakephp 3

**My Controller is**

```
if(h($this->request->data['image']['name']) != '')
                    {
                        $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($this->request->data['image']['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
                        $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'); //set allowed extensions

                        if (in_array($ext, $arr_ext)) 
                        {
                            $extension = pathinfo($_FILES["image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                            if($extension=='jpg' || $extension=='jpeg' || $extension=='png')
                            {
                                if ($this->request->data['image']['size'] < '26214400')
                                {
                                    $randno         = rand(0,100);
                                    $filenameArr    = explode('.' , h($this->request->data['image']['name']));
                                    $namefile       = $filenameArr[0].$randno;
                                    $extfile        = $filenameArr[1];
                                    $filename       = WWW_ROOT .'uploads/users/'.$namefile.'.'.$extfile;
                                    move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['image']['tmp_name'], $filename);
                                    $upload         = $namefile.'.'.$extfile;
                                    $newData['image'] = $upload;
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $this->Flash->error(__('Please upload only jpg or jpeg or png type image '));
                                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit', $id]);
                            }                      
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->Flash->error(__('Please only upload images (jpeg, png, jpg).'));
                            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit', $id]);
                        }
                    }
```

But It's only executing else condition even when i put correct extension.

Comment: Check what you're getting in `$ext`, I suspect you may be surprised.

Comment: Yeah i changed it from $check to $this->request->data but it just checking the extension but when i upload a .exe file after changing it's extension like chrome-setup.exe to chrome-setup.jpg then it's running and uploading the image but i want that if someone change extension then it not allow to upload it's shows error.

Comment: you must check file mime type https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: I put it in my if condition **if(in_array(mime_content_type($this->request->data['image']['name']), $arr_ext))** but still it executing else condition

Comment: Such checks must be performed on the file, not the file name, eg `tmp_name`, not `name`. Also you should look into using [**CakePHP's built in validation functionality**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/validation.html). Also you shouldn't use superglobals like `$_FILES` when using CakePHP, always use the abstracted APIs provided by the framework instead!

Comment: Thank You so much i got the correct answer